# I cannot display information after typing pwd --held in the terminal

Tags: terminal

I cannot display information after typing `pwd --held` in the terminal. I've tried many times unsuccessfully.

Anyone can help ?

Comment: do you mean `--help`, not `--held`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing to "display information" at all here. Do you mean that `pwd --held; echo "output here"` means that `output here` isn't printed? Providing a [mre] others can run to see the same behavior (including simplified code, and both your actual output and expected output from that code) goes a long way towards ensuring that a question is answerable.

Comment: (Also, `pwd` isn't part of your terminal -- it's part of your shell; so which shell you're using matters, and should be included in the question. I'm not familiar with `--held` being an available option for `pwd` in _any_ shell, but if you specified which one you're using or which docs indicated that it was an option you could expect to have provided, that too would be useful).

Answer (score 0):

sorry, it's pwd -- help.

I am following a developper training and learning how to use a terminal. Print Working Directory is the the instruction that i have to use. After typing pwd --held it must display what i have in the computer.